# Mongoose Find By Ref ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

so I have two schemas, User und Company

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _createdAt: Date,
    company: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'company'},
    email: String,
});


const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const userModel = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema, "user");
const companyModel = mongoose.model("company", CompanySchema, "company");
```

I would now like to query for a specific User by his Company _id, but for some reason this is not working, it returns an empty array even though I have a user with the exact company ObjectId in my Database.

```
userModel.find({company: "5cfa4352ffc1c8135d8276a4"})
         .exec((err, user) => {
             console.log(user);
         }
```

In my mongo shell the command

```
db.user.find({company: "5cfa4352ffc1c8135d8276a4"})
```

returns the users as expected so why does this not work in mongoose? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Jan Schmutz, did you manage to find a solution to this? I am in a similar situation as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find by that id you probably need to do this:

```
const mongojs = require('mongojs');
const ObjectId = mongojs.ObjectId;

db.user.find({company: ObjectId("5cfa4352ffc1c8135d8276a4")})
```

Since you are using moongose, you can get the ObjectId like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const objectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('569ed8269353e9f4c51617aa')
```

Comment: nope I tried that before, it also doesn't work, also if I query for the user _id I also don't need this Syntax, thx for the Response though

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

then

```
db.user.find({company: ObjectId("5cfa4352ffc1c8135d8276a4")})
```

I hope it will work